# How to make slider working on a cloned HTML-page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, httrack

I have cloned html page containing a slider by means of HTTrack tool. But it looks static and does not move. Actually this is a snapshot of the current state of the slider without the possibility to change its state despite all links to images are available. How can I make it working?

Comment: can you download the html page from the browser?

Comment: Yes, I can but result is the same

Comment: Open the page in browser, press `F12` to bring up the developer console, see if there are any error messages. Depending on the detailed implementation of the slider it may behave unexpectedly being cloned.

Comment: Of course there are errors in the console, but it looks like there is nothing related to slider itself.The slider consisting from 4 images looks like freezed on the 3-rd one (the third button is selected and there is no way to switch to another one)